# WEBVTT usage with correct X-TIMESTAMP-MAP such that VLC will synchronize

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I have a VTT subtitle file where the first lines looks like the following

```
WEBVTT
X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:1810830,LOCAL:00:00:00.000

00:35:43.618 --> 00:35:46.138
```

Because the sub titles in fact should start at 00:00:00.000 I tried to change the X-TIMESTAMP-MAP like the following
`X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:0,LOCAL:00:35:00.000` (or `X-TIMESTAMP-MAP=MPEGTS:1810830,LOCAL:00:35:00.000` and several other variations).

Unfortunately neither vlc nor parole media player change anything in their behaviour, and start the sub titles only at 00:35:34, although they should start at 00:00:00.

Am I doing something wrong, or are they just not using that information? (Any Linux player which accepts this information?)

Any other way to fix all my files single sub title entries time stamps (on Linux), so that they start these 35m earlier?